# Скролл с автодоведением

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток. Я хотел бы получить помощь в реализации скролла с автодоведением.
(Поясню. К примеру у меня х-скролл, скроллятся кнопки, на экране помещается скажем ровно 4. Если в результате скроллинга крайняя кнопка оказалась частично за экраном, то смещение должно продолжиться так, что бы либо она скрылась полностью, либо откатилась и полностью появилась)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо слелать так:

1. Переопределить `ScrollView.onScrollChanged()`
2. Если в новой позиции кнопка перекрывается то добавить/убавить скроллирование. Вычислить перекрытие можно по примеру показанному [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628800/android-how-to-check-if-a-view-inside-of-scrollview-is-visible)

**Update** автодоводку скроллинга (чтобы было красиво, типа как отскок) - лучше сделать через `View.postDelayed()` - тогда доводка будет через какое-то время